Проблема с формой на сайте
Проблема с формой на сайте. Давно была блокировка отправки почты с моего сервера, недавно сняли, на период блокировки соответственно письма на почту не приходили ни с одной из 4 форм. После блокировки 3 формы заработали, но одна все равно не хочет отправляться. Делал SQL-запрос SELECT * FROM b_event, но там не то что письма не отправлены, там они просто не появляются даже. Нужно что-то делать с формой. Сайт на битриксе.
Вот исходный код:
<div class="container mh800">
    <div class="c-middle">
        <div class="c-middle__content">
                <?php if ($arResult['RESULT']) { ?>
                    <?php if($arResult['RESULT']['ERROR']) {
                        echo $arResult['RESULT']['ERROR'];
                    } else {?>
                        <span class="promocode_text"><?=$arResult['RESULT']['NAME']?>, благодарим за заполнение нашего квиза!<br/>Ваша скидка в 3% доступна по следующему промокоду</span>
                        <h2 class="promocode_value"><?=$arResult['RESULT']['PROMOCODE']?></h2>
                        
                        <?
                        $arSelect = Array("ID", "NAME", "DATE_ACTIVE_FROM", "PROPERTY_room_type", "PROPERTY_room_square", "PROPERTY_floor_type", "PROPERTY_property_type", "PROPERTY_work_start", "PROPERTY_city", "PROPERTY_phone", "PROPERTY_mail", "PROPERTY_promocode");
                        $arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID"=>24, "ID"=>$arResult['RESULT']['ID']);
                        $res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, false, $arSelect);
                        if ($ob = $res->GetNext())
                        {   
                            ?>
                            <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        ym(59248438, 'reachGoal', 'hochu_skidku');
        ym(59248438, 'reachGoal', 'lead');
        var ct_site_id = '70981';
        var ct_data = {   
            room_type: '<?=CIBlockElement::GetByID($ob['PROPERTY_ROOM_TYPE_VALUE'])->GetNext()?>',
            room_square: '<?=CIBlockElement::GetByID($ob['PROPERTY_ROOM_SQUARE_VALUE'])->GetNext()?>',
            floor_type: '<?=CIBlockElement::GetByID($ob['PROPERTY_FLOOR_TYPE_VALUE'])->GetNext()?>',
            property_type: '<?=CIBlockElement::GetByID($ob['PROPERTY_PROPERTY_TYPE_VALUE'])->GetNext()?>',
            work_start: '<?=CIBlockElement::GetByID($ob['PROPERTY_WORK_START_VALUE'])->GetNext()?>',
            spb: '<?=CIBlockElement::GetByID($ob['PROPERTY_CITY_VALUE'])->GetNext()?>',
            phone: '<?=$ob['PROPERTY_PHONE_VALUE']?>',
            mail: '<?=$ob['PROPERTY_MAIL_VALUE']?>',
            name: '<?=$arResult['RESULT']['NAME']?>',
            promocode: '<?=$arResult['RESULT']['PROMOCODE']?>',
            subject: 'Заявка с сайта',
            comment: 'Хочу скидку',
            requestUrl: location.href,
            sessionId: window.ct('calltracking_params', 'ohadt7w7').sessionId
        };


        $.ajax({  
            url: 'https://api.calltouch.ru/calls-service/RestAPI/requests/' + ct_site_id + '/register/',      
            dataType: 'json',         
            type: 'POST',          
            data: ct_data
        }); 
    }, 500);
});

</script>
                            <?
                        }
                        ?>
                        <a href="/" class="button button--blue">На главную</a>
                        
                    <?php }
                    ?>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <div class="static-form-container" id="top-anchor">
                        <form id="questioner_form" method="post" class="static-form-wrapper" novalidate>
                            <input type="hidden" name="room_type" id="room_type" value="">
                            <input type="hidden" name="room_square" id="room_square" value="">
                            <input type="hidden" name="floor_type" id="floor_type" value="">
                            <input type="hidden" name="property_type" id="property_type" value="">
                            <input type="hidden" name="work_start" id="work_start" value="">
                            <input type="hidden" name="spb" id="spb" value="">
                            <input type="hidden" name="session_id" id="session_id" value="">
                            <input type="hidden" name="request" value="send">
                            <?php
                            $iFieldsCount = count($arResult['FIELDS']) + 1;
                            $iCurrentPercent = 0;
                            ?>
                            <?php foreach ($arResult['FIELDS'] as $i => $arField):
                                $iCurrentPercent = intval(100 / $iFieldsCount) * $i;
                                ?>
                                <div class="static-form <?= ($i == 0 ? 'active' : '') ?> static-form__page-<?= $arField['ID'] ?>">
                                    <div class="static-form__title"><?= $arField['NAME'] ?></div>
                                    <div class="static-form__error_text"></div>
                                    <?php if ($arField['PROPERTY_TYPE'] == 'E'): ?>
                                        <div class="static-form__fields <?= (count($arField['VALUES']) == 2 ? 'w50' : '') ?>">
                                            <?php foreach ($arField['VALUES'] as $arOption): ?>
                                                <div class="static-form__field popup__field radio">
                                                    <input class="radio__input" type="radio"
                                                           name="PROPERTY_<?= $arField['ID'] ?>"
                                                           id="<?= $arField['CODE'] ?>_<?= $arOption['ID'] ?>"
                                                           value="<?= $arOption['ID'] ?>">
                                                    <label class="radio__label"
                                                           for="<?= $arField['CODE'] ?>_<?= $arOption['ID'] ?>"><?= $arOption['NAME'] ?></label>
                                                </div>
                                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php elseif ($arField['PROPERTY_TYPE'] == 'S'): ?>
                                        <div class="static-form__fields w100">
                                            <div class="static-form__field popup__field">
                                                <label for="static-form__field-<?= $arField['CODE'] ?>"
                                                       class="popup__field-label"><?= $arField['NAME'] ?></label>
                                                <input id="static-form__field-<?= $arField['CODE'] ?>"
                                                       class="popup__field-input" type="text"
                                                       name="PROPERTY_<?= $arField['ID'] ?>" required>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <div class="static-form__progress">
                                        <div class="static-form__progress-bar"
                                             style="width: <?= (100 / $iFieldsCount) * ($i) ?>%"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="static-form__submit">
                                        <?php if ($i > 0): ?>
                                            <a class="button button--gray" href="#top-anchor">Назад</a>
                                        <?php endif ?>
                                        <a class="button button--blue" href="#top-anchor">Далее</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                            <div class="static-form  static-form__page-7">
                                <div class="static-form__title">Контактные данные</div>
                                <div class="static-form__error_text"></div>
                                <div class="static-form__fields">
                                    <div class="static-form__field popup__field">
                                        <label for="static-form__field-name" class="popup__field-label">Имя</label>
                                        <input id="static-form__field-name" class="popup__field-input" type="text"
                                               name="name" required novalidate>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="static-form__field popup__field">
                                        <label for="static-form__field-phone" class="popup__field-label">Контактный
                                            телефон</label>
                                        <input id="static-form__field-phone" class="popup__field-input" type="text"
                                               name="PROPERTY_85" required novalidate>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="static-form__field popup__field">
                                        <label for="static-form__field-mail" class="popup__field-label">Контактный
                                            email</label>
                                        <input id="static-form__field-mail" class="popup__field-input" type="email"
                                               name="PROPERTY_86" required novalidate>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="static-form__field popup__field w50 static-form__field__data_processing">
                                        <input class="d-sidebar__checkbox" type="checkbox" name="data_processing"
                                               id="data_processing"
                                               value="Y" required novalidate>
                                        <label class="d-sidebar__item-label" for="data_processing">Я согласен на <a
                                                    href="#top-anchor">обработку данных</a></label>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <div class="static-form__progress">
                                    <div class="static-form__progress-bar"
                                         style="width: <?= $iCurrentPercent + intval(100 / $iFieldsCount) ?>%"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="static-form__submit">
                                    <a class="button button--gray" href="#top-anchor">Назад</a>
                                    <button type="submit" class="button button--blue">Отправить</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Куда рыть - не знаю.

как задать хороший вопрос. начните с формулировки загооловка, например.
